# Previous ticket # for Jet Blue

Tags: jetblue

I need to find the ticket #'s for a flight from JFK to Hawaii that my husband and I took in May of this year to claim points from Jet Blue. Any idea where to look? I unfortunately disposed of our boarding passes with that info after we arrived.

Comment: Most tickets these days are emailed. Perhaps you can find the email again?

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this was a boarding pass that was printed at our resort and hadn't been emailed to us. I sure wish it had tho!

Comment: How did your resort get the boarding pass to print? Didn't you need to supply them with a ticket confirmation or booking number?

Comment: They just needed the flight confirmation code. The actual ticket # was printed on the boarding pass,

Comment: Where did you get the booking reference? In an email? That email will usually also contain the e-ticket number.

Comment: The email only showed the flight #'s and confirmation # - no ticket #'s

Comment: Can you use that to log in to the airine's "manage my booking" faciity? Otherwise contact whoever *sent* that email.

Comment: @PMurtha any updates? Did that help?